# How can I read an empty line in Java?

Tags: java, string, input

I want to be able to read an empty line if the user presses enter, but at the same time I want to be able to read a line with content if he inserts any.

```
System.out.println("Name> ");
String nome = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("--" + nome + "--");
System.out.println("Id> ");
String id = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(" ")
```

The problem is that everytime the user inserts any content, I only receive an empty String.

Comment: What do you do with `sc` before `sc.nextLine()` - do you have a call like `sc.next()` or `sc.nextDouble()` ?

Comment: From that snippet, you're not printing `id` out, just an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

I think sc is a scanner object so I have completed your code like this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Name> ");
    String nome = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("--" + nome + "--");
    System.out.println("Id> ");
    String id = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" ");
```

this works fine

```
this is the output for a line with content 
Name> 
wahidullah
--wahidullah--
Id> 
200
```

and

```
this is the ouput for an empty line
Name> 

----
Id>
```

hopes this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @[Wahidullah Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13857453/wahidullah-shadab).

But, I believe the problem in your case is caused by using ***nextLine()*** right after ***nextInt()***,***next()***,etc.
I make this assumption based on the fact that you have provided only a small piece of your code.

The problem is, ***nextInt()*** does not consume ***return character***. When ***nextLine()*** is called right after that, it simply consumes the ***return character***, thus giving you empty string.

Research Links:

- [Stack Overflow question on Scanner skipping '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo#:%7E:text=It%27s%20because%20when%20you%20enter,buffer%20from%20the%20first%20input.)
- [Oracle Docs on "nextLine()"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())